# Can なければなりません apply to previous clause joined with て

Tags: grammar, て-form

> 気象庁は「まだ火山の活動が続いているので、これからどうなるか気をつけて**見ていかなければなりません**」と話しています。
>   The JMA said "Because volcanic activity is still continuing, we'll have to pay attention to what happens from now on, and go and look at it."

I'm not 100% confident in my translation. My assumption is that なければなりません applies to both clauses 見ていく and 気をつける. If not, then I can't make the two clauses link together in any logical way.

Assuming my assumptions are correct would it also be natural to swap the order of these clauses:

> 見ていってこれからどうなるか気をつけなければなりません。
>   We have to go and look at it and pay attention to what's happening.

In English this order feels more natural, but I have no idea about Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to think of the 気をつけて here is as a quasi-adverbial usage modifying 見ていく. In other words, 気をつけて見ていく refers to the single action of "carefully watching over it going forward".

Note that the いく in 見ていく here does not literally refer to going anywhere, but is part of the common ～ていく usage meaning "to do something from now on". If the meaning was "go and look at it", it would have to be 見**に**行く.

Comment: Perfect. Mixing up 見ていく and 見に行く is exactly what was tripping me up here. Thanks.